# I got an error in Android Studio. Gradle Project sync Failed

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins, zscaler

At first it was showing Server Certificate is not trusted. Then I checked under Server Certificates, those certificates were from zscaler and were expired. I deleted those certificates, then my error was on plugins.

Here is how my Build looks[Android Studio Build Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEukF.png)

Please Help

Comment: Try making the IDE Gradle plugin version same as the gradle version

Answer (score 1):

you need to carefully check settings studio should automatically download gradle 7.1.2 why it is not updating. Change it to 7.1.1 or 7.0.2 and sync see build is successful or not. Go to file > settings or tools>settings. Click Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle check use gradle from and download external..checkbox is checked. Check Remote Jar Dependencies under same tree. Click Tools > SDK Manager. Check Updates are on or not. Install API 32 also.